# Purchase Number shows default value rather than the dynamic values

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, eloquent

I have the following AJAX,

```
  select: function(event, ui) {
    $( function() {
        var aravaitaken_date = $('#aravaitaken_date').val();
        var purchase_number = $('#purchase_number').val();
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "getAravaiTotalbyDate",
            type: "POST",
            data: { aravaitaken_date: aravaitaken_date, purchase_number: purchase_number },
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('.calculation').html("<div class='row'><div class='col-md-12 text-center'><br/><br/><br/><br/><img src='images/ajax-loader.gif'/></div></div>");
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('.calculation').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
  }
```

and the input form which i gave was ,

```
<label for="autocompletion">Purchase: </label> <input id="autocompletion">
```

And the function of the respective was,

```
public function getAravaiTotalbyDate(Request $request){

        $input = $request->all();
        $aravaitaken_date = $input['aravaitaken_date'];
    $purchase_number = $input['purchase_number'];

        $aravaitaken_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($aravaitaken_date));


    $aravaitaken_total_moottai = DB::table('take_aravais')->where('sale_date', '=',$aravaitaken_date)->where('purchase_number', '=', $purchase_number)->sum("moottai");
    $aravaitaken_total_kuvintal = DB::table('take_aravais')->where('sale_date' , '=', $aravaitaken_date)->where('purchase_number', '=',$purchase_number)->sum("kuvintal");

        $id = Settings::all()->last()->id;
        $percentage = Settings::findOrFail($id);
        $percentage_rice = $percentage->rice_percentage;
        $percentage_kurunai = $percentage->kurunai_percentage;
        $percentage_thavudu = $percentage->thavudu_percentage;

        $aravu_seithathil_varavu_total_kuvintal = $percentage_rice * $aravaitaken_total_kuvintal / 100;
        $aravu_seithathil_varavu_total_kuvintal_kurunai = $percentage_kurunai * $aravaitaken_total_kuvintal / 100;
        $aravu_seithathil_varavu_total_kuvintal_thavudu = $percentage_thavudu * $aravaitaken_total_kuvintal / 100;

        return view('Purchase.calculation', compact('percentage', 'aravaitaken_total_moottai', 'aravaitaken_total_kuvintal', 'aravu_seithathil_varavu_total_kuvintal', 'aravu_seithathil_varavu_total_kuvintal_kurunai', 'aravu_seithathil_varavu_total_kuvintal_thavudu'));

    }
```

And the output is like the image shown,

[image]

Here i select a purchase number 21, but it is showing some default value as 5 but i didn't set any value to purchase number.. When i console it, the date is coming in correct manner but the purchase number is coming as "5" for whatever the purchase number i enter it is showing only 5 .. Any help that solve my problem would be appreciable..

Comment: Just check the request being sent from the console. Click that getAravailTotalByDate request you see in console and you'll what's being sent to server. If it's 5 here then no need to check server code. Problem is with retrieval of purchase number from the text box.  Check the value as suggested by Subi by using alert. If it's 5 even there. Then please use  console.log($('#purchase_number')); and check if it print's the correct textbox in console. It's possible that you may have some other hidden field somewhere with same ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Can't See your html code here, so first check purchase number you are sending to the ajax

```
select: function(event, ui) {
$( function() {
    var aravaitaken_date = $('#aravaitaken_date').val();
    var purchase_number = $('#purchase_number').val();

//alert  a purchase number to check the value
alert(purchase_number);



    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "getAravaiTotalbyDate",
        type: "POST",
        data: { aravaitaken_date: aravaitaken_date, purchase_number: purchase_number },
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('.calculation').html("<div class='row'><div class='col-md-12 text-center'><br/><br/><br/><br/><img src='images/ajax-loader.gif'/></div></div>");
        },
        success: function(data){
            $('.calculation').html(data);
        }
    });
 });
}
```

if the purchase number is correct just change your ajax data like this

```
data: { "aravaitaken_date": aravaitaken_date, "purchase_number": purchase_number },
```

if everything on the ajax and javascript part is correct just check the php side like

```
public function getAravaiTotalbyDate(Request $request){

    $input = $request->all();
    $aravaitaken_date = $input['aravaitaken_date'];
    $purchase_number = $input['purchase_number'];

    echo $purchase_number;

}
```

I hope You Are Understanding That....

Comment: I have updated my code with input, and the problem was solved.. The problem is in input i gave id=autocompletion , but in Ajax i gave var purchase_number = $(#purchase_number) .. Here comes the major issue and now rectified it.. up vote and accepting ur answer for your help..

Comment: Thank you Mani Raj,  Thanku You Soo Much For Voting My Ans And my best wishes for your project

Comment: I can understand your tamil words in that code cz i'm also tamil

Comment: Oh which place?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143940/discussion-between-mani-raj-and-subi).